# mule 3.9.5 Cannot transform xml dom to xml

Tags: xml, mule

After migration the mule server from 3.9.1 to 3.9.5, I encountered a problem in the transformation of the payload to xml.

Here is my code:

```
<flow name="SetVariablesFromPBGB">
   <foreach collection="#[xpath3('/*:Envelope/*:Header',payload,'NODESET')]" doc:name="For Each">
      <mulexml:dom-to-xml-transformer doc:name="DOM to XML"/>
      <mulexml:xslt-transformer xsl-file="removeNameSpace.xslt" maxIdleTransformers="2" maxActiveTransformers="5" doc:name="XSLT"/>:
      <set-variable variableName="soapHeader" value="#[System.getProperty('line.separator')]#[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]"/>
   </foreach>
</flow>
```

The dom-to-xml-transformer don't transform the payload to xml:

After this line the payload still [soapenv:Header: null]  instead of :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Header>
</soapenv:Header>
```

Comment: What is the input payload and it's type for the flow?

Comment: <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Header>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
<import>
<data><![CDATA[
<AAA>
<BBB></BBB>
</AAA>]]></data>
</import>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

Comment: I'll assume the type is a string, right?

Comment: yes, here i just set an empty header

Comment: What is the expected result of this flow?

Comment: I need to remove the namespace from the header, for that i retrieve the header from the payload, transform it to xml and set the new header without namespace

Comment: I submitted an answer. Please let me know if it is helpful.

Comment: Please accept the answer if useful or let me know if there is any issue with it.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that you want to get the soapEnv:Header element with the prefix `soapEnv:` but without the namespace declaration for it. I'm not sure that is valid usage of namespaces according to the [XML Namespaces specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/#ns-using):

> The namespace prefix, unless it is xml or xmlns, MUST have been declared in a namespace declaration attribute in either the start-tag of the element where the prefix is used or in an ancestor element (i.e., an element in whose content the prefixed markup occurs).

If having the namespace declared is acceptable this DataWeave script could replace the flow's body:

```js
<dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
    <dw:input-payload mimeType="application/xml" />
    <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
    %dw 1.0
    %output application/xml
    ---
    payload.Envelope.*Header 
    ]]>     
    </dw:set-payload>
</dw:transform-message>
```

Input:

```xml
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope">  <soapenv:Header><t>a</t></soapenv:Header>  <soapenv:Body> <import> <data><![CDATA[ <AAA> <BBB></BBB> </AAA>]]></data> </import> </soapenv:Body> </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Output:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<soapenv:Header xmlns:soapenv="schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope">
  <t>a</t>
</soapenv:Header>
```

If you want to remove completely the XML namespaces you can use the method adapted from this [blog](https://programmingatease.wordpress.com/2019/12/28/remove-xml-namespaces-in-the-xml-and-output-plain-xml-through-dataweave/) by using a recursive function. This removes completely namespaces declarations **and** the prefixes.

```js
%dw 1.0
%output application/xml
---
Header: payload.Envelope.Header
```

Output (for the same input above):

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Header>
  <t>a</t>
</Header>
```

Those are the valid XML outputs that you can perform.

**NOT RECOMMENDED**: If you absolutely must generate invalid XML then you can convert the XML to a string and perform string replacement or regex operation to remove the undesired. Be aware that performing string manipulations on XML is a bad practice. I strongly advise to avoid implementing this and to avoid generating invalid XML.

Example:

```js
%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
// warning: transforming the XML with string operations is not recommended!
write(payload.Envelope.*Header,"application/xml")
```

This returns a Java string that can be manipulated inside DataWeave, Java code, MEL scripts or Groovy scripts.

Comment: Please i have a question, to use dw, do i have to have an EE version.

Comment: It is possible that in Mule 3 DataWeave is an Enterprise Edition only feature. However the Mule versions you are using (3.9.1, 3.9.5) are EE releases only so it should not be a problem.